# All static assets not loading - Django, Gunicorn, NGINX

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.04, gunicorn, Django, and Nginx. Every time I load the main page: http://dev.api.afisado.com, none of the CSS is loaded and the js is executed. From the developer tab in Chrome, I see a 404 not found. I'm not sure what to do.

The folder Structure is like this:

```
/home/devbackend_directory/core/static/
```

Here is what my settings.py looks like:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/devbackend_directory/core/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/devbackend_directory'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

the nginx file:

```
server
 listen 80;
        server_name dev.api.afisado.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}

        location static/ {

                root /home/devbackend_directory/core/static/;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
```

and here is my gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target


[Service]
User=ali
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/devbackend_directory/core/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn \
         --access-logfile - \
         --workers 3 \
         --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
         core.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you use `collectstatic` ?

Comment: From which directory am I supposed to execute that? How will nginx know to look in the new static directory?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run collectstatic, when DEBUG is set to False, Django doesn't go looking for static directory inside the apps, it has to be in specified location. And if it still doesn't work, try the following settings, which is what I usually do when hosting
urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path as url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Where should I execute collectstatic from? Does my settings and nginx file look OK?

Comment: its a manage.py command.
I don't think it has anything to do with nginx.
Your settings.py looks alright, although I prefer giving relative path.
Keep in note that once you run collectstatic, Django will generate a new static folder in the project directory. So point the STATIC_ROOT to this folder

Comment: Oh, and point nginx to this folder too